# Count of Profiles Where One or All Expiration Dates Are Before Current Date

Tags: sql, count, distinct

I need help with a query (and its' subquery).  Each record in the table can have one or more identifiers, each of which having its own expiration date.  I want to count how many records only have expired identifier dates, no matter how many there are (all are expired).  I think that I'm not eliminating the records that have several identifiers where one is expired but the others are current.

```
SELECT COUNT(IDENTIFIER_ROWID)
FROM BO_IDENTIFIER_TABLE
WHERE (SELECT DISTINCT IDENTIFIER_ROWID 
        FROM BO_IDENTIFIER_TABLE WHERE IDENT_END_DT < (sysdate)
```

And that is where I get stuck.  I know I need a subquery to bring back the profiles with only old/expired dates, and then count those up in the main query, but I'm not writing it correctly.  Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you please post some sample data and expected output.

Comment: @user2989408,
So here's some sample data (sorry if the formatting changes):  
Rowid_Object ID_St ID_No ID_End_Dt  
12345 AR C-1234 12/31/2010  
12345 AR C-2345 12/31/2013  
23456 NJ NJ-1234 12/31/2008  
23456 DE DE-1234 12/31/2013  
23456 PA PA-1234 12/31/2016  
34567 CA CA-1234 12/31/2012  
  
So, the query would look initially like this:  
SELECT COUNT(Rowid_Object)  
FROM BO_IDENTIFIER_TABLE  
WHERE (SELECT DISTINCT Rowid_Object  
FROM BO_IDENTIFIER_TABLE WHERE ID_END_DT <= (sysdate))

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? Counts distinct records not found in a subquery with unexpired IDs. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/81611/2/0